# Quick question: how can I initialise a LIST-ITEM-PAIRS of a selection-list?

Tags: initialization, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6.

I'm trying to initialise a `SELECTION-LIST`, but not with `LIST-ITEMS`, but with `LIST-ITEM-PAIRS`.

In order to initialise with `LIST-ITEMS`, I needed to do the following:

```
sl-SELECTION_LIST:LIST-ITEMS = "".
```

When I try this, for `LIST-ITEM-PAIRS`, this seems not to work:

```
sl-SELECTION_LIST:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS = "".
```

This gives the error that the number of entries must be even.

```
sl-SELECTION_LIST:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS = ",".
```

This puts an empty line as the first entry of the `SELECTION-LIST`.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
sl-SELECTION_LIST:LIST-ITEM-PAIRS = ?.
```